# django models field relation on it itself

Tags: django, models

I can't decide which is best way to relate django models field with it own other field. I have Match class which possess field teams(m-t-m filed on other model) and i need to store match result with corresponding score for each team. It can be only 2 team in one match.

```
class Match(models.Model):
 teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)
 tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
 match_round = models.ForeignKey(Round)
 team_1_hit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
 team_2_hit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: If can be only 2 team in one match, then that's ok. And I'd rather will create two fields `team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team)` and `team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team)` instead of `teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)`

Comment: I did this at first. But it can't be 2 foreign key on one model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay to have two `ForeignKey` fields in this situation. `ManyToManyField` could cause errors, when 3 teams will be added. So you could specify two `ForeignKey` fields with [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

```
class Match(models.Model):
    team1 = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='team1')
    team2 = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='team2')
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament)
    match_round = models.ForeignKey(Round)
    team_1_hit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    team_2_hit = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Yes, thanx a lot! That's what i was looking for!

Comment: But related_name - it's an attribute on the Team model. May be that's better: `team1 = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='home_matches')`, `team2 = models.ForeignKey('Team', related_name='away_matches`)` or something like this